# how to check check box and getting whether checkbox is checked in javascript selenium

Tags: selenium, javascript

how to check check box and getting whether checkbox is checked in javascript selenium and node. I tried using .click on the element also tried using native javascript code to do that.but nothing worked for me.

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('//*    
[@id="myTable"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/input')).
then(function(element){
   element.click().then(function(){//body goes here

};
```

I have edited the code in SO itself so there might be braces problem.in actual code its not the braces problem.

any solutions to do so?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use JS - use .checked to get if checkbox is checked

Like in this example:

```
return document.getElementsByName('element_name')[0].checked;
```

If you want to know whether element was selected with Selenium use .isSelected()

```
element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='element_name']"));
check=web.isSelected();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting attribute `"checked"`. If your checkbox is selected, it will return true or it will return false or null.